# Making my drop down menu central on the page

Tags: html, css

I have made this little drop down menu here on JS fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/WeEzy/ but i really need to have it centred on the page, If anyone could help me do this it would be greatly appreciated,

Also if anyone don't mind please could you help me make it so when the browser squeezes below 500px it changes into a drop down list like on the picture on this wiki  page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list 
I have tried to do this but am really struggling, i believe its ,

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {}.
```

Please if you could make my menubar centred that would be great but if you can please help me make this drop down,

Thankyou all very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of centering the menu, add the following to your css ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/WeEzy/5/)):

```
.top-nav{
    width:100%;
}
.top-nav > ul{
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Alternatively, if you dont want to specify a fixed width for the menu (e.g. if more items may be added) (**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/WeEzy/6/)**):

```
.top-nav > ul {
    text-align:center;
}
.top-nav > ul >li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
}
.top-nav > ul ul {
    text-align:left;
}
.top-nav ul ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

TO produce a dropdown, add the following below your CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    .top-nav ul ul {
        position: relative;
    }
    .top-nav li {
        float:none;
    }
    .top-nav li ul{
         display:block;   
    }
    .buttons{
        padding:0;
}
```

## [Fiddle with alignment and dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/WeEzy/9/)

Comment: Hello, Thankyou very much for your solution :D, With the drop down menu i would really like it just basic as possible so that i can understand it, As you can see on this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list  there is a image or a very basic drop down, this is all i would like, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.top-nav > ul{text-align:center;}
.top-nav > ul >li {float:none; display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css**

```
.top-nav{text-align:center;}
.buttons{display:inline-block;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WeEzy/4/)**